# Embed ember-cli app into another one

Tags: ember.js

I want to share an application between to other *container* apps, both done in Ember. So the app have to communicate with the parent container and should be compiled just one time.

What is the correct way to do this? Use an iframe and communicate with `App.__container__.lookup('controller:application')`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an iframe is going to do the trick. Check out Ember Engines: http://ember-engines.com

Comment: `an engine does not boot itself` and if one of the app doesn't use ember-cli?

Comment: You mentioned 'container' apps, which would boot them. I haven't used an iframe in a long time, but I don't see how an app in an iFrame would be able to communicate with the parent in a normal Ember way. They could both connect to the same backend - and reflect those changes. Good Luck! I'd love to hear about how you solve it. You should write an article about it.